# Confusion in Duality Principle in Boolean Algebra

Tags: boolean-algebra

Maybe I have got some misconception while solving a problem.
Lets a logic function,
X=AB+A'C

By applying duality principle, I can say that, X=(A+B)(A'+C)

But I can't prove both are equal. I simplify upto this,

(A+B)(A'+C)=AC+A'B

For an input, A=0, B=0, C=1
X=AB+A'C=1
But X=(A+B)(A'+C)=0.1=0

As is shown both are not equal. Where is my problem with the duality principle?

Comment: Never seen such condition yet

Answer (score 3):

I think you misapplied the duality principle. It should be:

AB+A'C is equivalent to (A+C)(A'+B)

When applying the duality principle you have to transform variables into their negation as well as interchanging ANDs and ORs.

The dual of X = AB+A'C is X' = (A'+B')*(A''+C').

Comment: Why? Shouldn’t I change AND operations with OR and vice versa?

Comment: Answer updated.

Answer (score 2):

The duality principle says that a statement stays true if we switch OR and AND operators, and we switch 0 and 1. With variables, it means we switch X and X'.

Take a simple example : X = A B
Thus you have: X' = A' + B'
Check the logic table:

\begin{array}{| c | c | c | c |}
\hline
a & b & x & x' \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
\hline
\end{array}

In your case you have: X = A B + A' C
Thus you have: X' = (A' + B') (A + C')

Comment: Should I do both simultaneously?  Like A+AB=A and A.(A+B)=A

Comment: I am not sure to understand your question. Yes you need to switch the operators and to invert the values/variables.
Inverting only the operators does not make sense. Just look at this not working example: X = A B = A + B, it is obviously not correct.